# Exporting to Excel with Web Part Connections

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, javascript, designer-workflow, calculated-column

Scenario - I created a meeting attendances sheet using a custom list. Here are the column titles Meeting (Single text column), Date (Date and time column), Start Time (Date and time column), End Time (Date and time column), Who Was There (Multiple line text column).

Problem & What am I trying to do - who was there to stay connected to the meeting, date, start time, end time columns.  Then I want it to be exported to excel the same way.  look at image.

How to solve - Thinking to create web part connections. If so what would be the best way of creating webpart connections.  Not sure but any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this without a lot of code customization may be to follow these steps:

1. Add another list to which only users who need to export data have read rights and has same fields as original list, additional lookup field with reference to original list and change "Who was there" to accept only one person.
2. Create a workflow on original list such that it runs in elevated privileges.
3. In workflow delete items from newly added list with current item's ID
4. Get value of "Who was there" as string and loop through each person
5. Add individual record for each user in newly created list.
6. Inform users to export data from this list.

Comment: Thank you Alok Kumar Gupta. question. 1. how do I accept only on person for "who was there"? for 2. how does elevated privileges help? 5. can you explain further?

Comment: For SharePoint 2013 workflows, following link may help for elevated priveleges https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx . For single value, when creating People/Group Field set value for "Allow multiple selections" as "No"